# Equivalent of Line Separator in smartGWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

Is there an equivalent or alternate for

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

It gives the below error

The method getProperty(String, String) in the type System is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, The method that am trying to use is not supported.  Only the below methods are supported from the System package.  System
err, out
System(), arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int), currentTimeMillis(), gc(), identityHashCode(Object), setErr(PrintStream), setOut(PrintStream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to execute `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in your server side code and access it using RPC or any other server side gwt communication technique.

Check [GWT JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html):

> GWT includes a library that emulates a subset of the Java runtime library. The list below shows the set of JRE packages, types and methods that GWT can translate automatically. Note that in some cases, only a subset of methods is supported for a given type.
>
> `System`
>
> `err, out` 
> `System()`, `arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)`, `currentTimeMillis()`, `gc()`, `getProperty(String, String)`, `identityHashCode(Object)`, `setErr(PrintStream)`, `setOut(PrintStream)`